# Parse multiple filters in SQL

Tags: sql-server, string

I have a problem parsing a stored procedure parameter in the form:

```
declare @S varchar(100)
set @S = '4=2,24=1534'
```

Here's the query:

```
    select 
        cast(idx as varchar(100)) 'idx'
    ,   value 
    ,   SUBSTRING(value, 1, charindex(value, '=')+1)  'first'
    ,   SUBSTRING(value, charindex(value, '=')+1, LEN(value)-charindex(value, '=')-1) 'second'
    from Common.SplitToTable(@S, ',') -- returns (idx int, value varchar(max))
    where len(value) > 0
```

But here is the result I get:

```
idx    value       first    second
0      4=2         4        4=
1      24=1534     2        24=153
```

Here's what I expected:

```
idx    value       first    second
0      4=2         4        2
1      24=1534     2        1534
```

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters to charindex are backwards (the string you are looking for comes first) and adjust the lengths accordingly:

```
select 
    cast(idx as varchar(100)) 'idx'
    ,   value 
    ,   SUBSTRING(value, 1, charindex('=', value)-1)  'first'
    ,   SUBSTRING(value, charindex('=', value)+1, LEN(value)-charindex('=',value)) 'second'
    from Common.SplitToTable(@S, ',') -- returns (idx int, value varchar(max))
    where len(value) > 0
```